# Grant Keycloak users with permissions

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I want to assign some permissions not roles to the user. How I can achieve this ?

Basically I assign the role of admin to user but now I want to attach the permission of Order:create so that I can use in my application.

In this given picture I can check the roles that are assign to this user in 99DPF client but How I can assign the permissions to user ?

[image]